# copy char* to another char** using dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am still new in this topic but can someone explain me how can I copy one char* to another char** as parameter without getting memory leaks?

```
void Hardware::copyString(char** dest, const char* source)
{
  size_t length = strlen(source);
  auto string = new char[length+1];
  strncpy(string, source, length);
  string[length] = '\0';
  *dest = string;
  //need to be freed
  free(string); //if i free here the data would getting lost
}
```

and a ctor:

```
Hardware::Hardware(const char* name, int cost)
{
 copyString(&name_, name);
 cost_ = cost;
}
```

main.cpp

```
Hardware hard("CPU", 250)
```

Where should I free this without getting memory leaks and have the right output?

Comment: "Where should I free this without getting memory leaks and have the right output?" Dont. use `std::string`.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code. Why don't you use `std::string`?

Comment: The problem is, i am not allowed to change the parameters data types that why i must works with it

Comment: Do you actually need to copy anything? In the example you’ve shown, there’s no need for this; simply store a pointer to the literal internally. Don’t copy it, don’t allocate any memory and don’t free it.

Comment: Since this seems to be an exercise on dynamic memory in a class, be sure to check the rule of three/five/zero (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regardless of the issues in your implementation, the simple answer to your question would be to free it at the destructor.

If you don't want to expose the `name_` variable, you can `free` it inside the destructor of the `Hardware` class.

```
Hardware::~Hardware()
{
    delete[] name_;
}
```

If you `free` is inside the function itself, you're deleting the heap allocation, even though you're passing different variables, because they're pointing to the same memory location.

But, as others suggested, the best way to work with strings is to use `std::string`.

Comment: thanks for your help! but i cant use char* test in main. It is restricted so i must  innitialiaze the member variable with the ctor

Comment: In that way, you can do it in the destructor, right?

Comment: @Joha: BTW, your question is not clear, and that's why many people (including me) got it wrong. Please mention your intention and the restrictions in the question itself.

Comment: Ahh yeah thats is what I am searching!! Thank You!

Comment: @Joha: Great! Don't forget to (upvote and) accept the answer so others won't get mislead.

Comment: You must not call `free` on a pointer allocated with `new[]`, this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: ^^^ don't use `free`, use `delete[]`. And don't forget to add or disable the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Sorry, I was just following the OPs path. Updated the answer.